# How can I compare s1 and s2 with no if statements in c++

Tags: c++, string, format

I am trying to do a code that follows these requirements, but I am having trouble finding a function that will properly compare `string1` and `string2` both of which are input in by user. Here is my code:

```
const int COLFMT1 = 20;
const int COLFMT2 = 20;

string s1;
string s2;
size_t lengths1;
// string s1ats2;
cout << "Welcome to String Squids!" << endl;
cout << "--------------------------" << endl;

cout << "Enter string 1 (at least three characters, no spaces): ";
cin >> s1;
cout << "Enter string 2 (no spaces): ";
cin >> s2;

// Show formatted strings

cout << "String 1" << setw(COLFMT1) << right << endl;
cout << "Value: " << setw(COLFMT1) << right << s1 << setw(COLFMT1) << left << endl << endl;

lengths1 = s1.length(); //gathering length of string 1
cout << "Length:" << setw(COLFMT1) << right << lengths1 << setw(COLFMT1) << left << endl << endl;

//s1ats2 = s2.find('s1',9);
//cout << s1ats2;
```

Here are the instructions:

> Format the following six outputs about `s1` into two formatted (no escape sequences) columns:
>
> - The contents of `s1`
> - The length of `s1`
> - The spot, if any, where `s2` is found within `s1`
> - Whether `s1[0]` is an alphabetic character

I am having trouble with the 3rd bullet, where `s2` is found within `s1`, and then also to identify if it is an alphabetic character.

Comment: Does this help [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

Comment: In general, code that you post should **demonstrate the problem** that you're asking about. The code here has nothing to do with the question; it's just stuff that deals with things that you know how to do. Show the code that's giving you trouble, not the code that isn't. Note that all that I/O has nothing to do with the problem; you'd have the same issue with fixed strings, and using fixed strings in your sample code would make it much easier for people to see what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

The first function you need is simply [`s1.find(s2)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

The second function will need to be [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalpha)

Answer (score -2):

> where s2 is found within s1

[std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

e.g.
`size_t pos = s1.find(s2);`

`pos` will be `std::string::npos` if s2 is not found in s1.  Otherwise, it is the offset of s2 located within s1.

> and then also to identify if it is an alphabetic character.

[isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/?kw=isalpha)

`bool isFirstCharacterAlphabetical = ((s1.size() > 0) && ::isalpha(s1[0]));`

Comment: Thank you! When I use the size_t, no matter what strings I input as user I get the return index of either 0 or 1 is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Sorry, wrong. This will search for **one** character of `s2` in `s1`.

Comment: [`std::string::find_first_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) finds the first single `char` that appears from the input string of possible `char`s. If you want to find an entire substring instead, use [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).